# Perform single selection with where

Tags: c#, .net, sql, subsonic

I'd like to achieve the following SQL statement with subsonic 2.2

```
SELECT Product.* FROM Product WHERE Product.OurPrice <> Product.RetailPrice
```

The Subsonic select query I've started with:

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery select = new SubSonic.Select()
.From<Product>()
.Where(Product.Columns.OurPrice)
.IsNotEqualTo(... object /*Should be Product.Columns.RetailPrice, but that's giving and exception*/...);
```

My question is how to tell SubSonic 2.2 to generate a where condition against another column in the same table.

Comment: The exception (snippet) is
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7469351
...
[FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType) +4872143
   ...
[SqlQueryException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.]
   SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteReader() +57
   SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollection() +80

Comment: What are the column types on your prices?  Could they have non-numeric data present or '$'?

Comment: The column types are decimal on both column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compare two columns within your query. This isn't possible in SubSonic 2.2 unless you use an inline query:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Inline_Query_Tool

You could also possibly use a view or table based function.

Comment: The inline query was working. It's a pity there is no other option only pure SQL. At least it's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem above:

```
ProductCollection products = new SubSonic.InlineQuery().ExecuteAsCollection<ProductCollection>
(@"SELECT Product.ProductId, ... Product.ModifiedBy, Product.ModifiedOn, Product.IsDeleted FROM Product WHERE (Product.OurPrice <> Product.RetailPrice)");

Repeater1.DataSource = products;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old Query object (still included in 2.2) like so:

```
Query q = new Query(Product.Schema.TableName).WHERE("OurPrice <> RetailPrice");
ProductCollection products = new ProductCollection();
products.LoadAndCloseReader(q.ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: Where returns a Constraint not a SqlQuery so that code won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the old Query object. I've updated my answer with the correct example